# How to inject additional dependencies / configuration into a decorated class

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have an `IRepository<>` and some `Setting` entity. I know that for this entity I will need a cached repository so I want to create a `ICachedRepository<Setting>` decorator and register it with Simple Injector.

The problem is that I have additional configuration that I need to pass somehow to the cached repository, e.g. expiration time span, prefetch policy, etc.

```
CachedRepository(IRepository repository, CachedRepositoryConfiguration configuration)
{
   ...
}
```

How can I do that? (These configuration can of course be different for different repositories, e.g. 30 minutes for one, 1 hour for another)

Comment: Since the configuration values themselves can be different for different repositories I would create different types instead of reusing the same type.  Alternatively you could do some "when-injected-into" stuff if the IoC library supports it, but I think this makes configuration more difficult, I would rather allow the IoC determine it by convention instead.

Comment: Having different type will lead to a problem because the repository is a generic. Unfortunately Simple Injector does not support "when-injected-into" out of the box, though it's possible to add this type of functionality. I thought maybe there is an easier way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Injector does not easily allow you to configure the constructor values of your decorators (although this can be done by [implementing a custom `IDependencyInjectionBehavior`](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility.html#overriding-parameter-injection-behavior) - or `IConstructorInjectionBehavior` in v2).

The easiest way around this is to fallback to property injection and register an initializer per decorator:

```cs
public class CachingRepositoryDecorator<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
{
    private readonly IRepository<TEntity> decoratee;
    public CachingRepositoryDecorator(IRepository<TEntity> decoratee) {
        this.decoratee = decoratee;
        this.Configuration = CachedRepositoryConfiguration.NoCaching;
    }

    public CachedRepositoryConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    // IRepository<T> methods here.
}

container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IRepository<>), 
    typeof(CachingRepositoryDecorator<>));

container.RegisterInitializer<CachingRepositoryDecorator<Setting>>(decorator => {
   decorator.Configuration = 
       CachedRepositoryConfiguration.AbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
});
```

Another option is to use [Context Based injection](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/2.8/advanced.html#context-based-injection). With the extension method given in the documentation you can do the following:

```cs
public class CachingRepositoryDecorator<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
{
    private readonly IRepository<TEntity> decoratee;
    private readonly CachedRepositoryConfiguration configuration;
    public CachingRepositoryDecorator(IRepository<TEntity> decoratee,
        CachedRepositoryConfiguration configuration) {
        this.decoratee = decoratee;
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    // IRepository<T> methods here.
}

container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IRepository<>), 
    typeof(CachingRepositoryDecorator<>));

container.RegisterWithContext<CachedRepositoryConfiguration>(context => {
    if (context.ImplementationType == typeof(CachingRepositoryDecorator<Setting>)) {
        return CachedRepositoryConfiguration.AbsExpiration(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
    } else {
        CachedRepositoryConfiguration.NoCaching;
    }
});
```

A third option is to make the configuration object generic as follows:

```cs
public class CachingRepositoryDecorator<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
{
    private readonly IRepository<TEntity> decoratee;
    private readonly CachedRepositoryConfiguration<TEntity> configuration;
    public CachingRepositoryDecorator(IRepository<TEntity> decoratee,
        CachedRepositoryConfiguration<TEntity> configuration) {
        this.decoratee = decoratee;
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    // IRepository<T> methods here.
}

container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IRepository<>), 
    typeof(CachingRepositoryDecorator<>));

container.RegisterSingleton<CachedRepositoryConfiguration<Setting>>(
    CachedRepositoryConfiguration<Setting>.Absolute(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)));

container.RegisterSingleton<CachedRepositoryConfiguration<Customer>>(
    CachedRepositoryConfiguration<Customer>.Sliding(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)));

// Register the 'no caching' configuration as fallback
container.Register(
    typeof(CachedRepositoryConfiguration<>),
    typeof(NoCachingCachedRepositoryConfiguration<>).
    Lifestyle.Singleton);

public sealed class NoCachingCachedRepositoryConfiguration<T>
    : CachedRepositoryConfiguration<T>
{
    public NoCachingCachedRepositoryConfiguration() : base(cache: false) { }
}
```

This third option allows you to remove the conditional registration altogether.

Comment: What if I use "Context based injection", will that not work with decorator?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik: Yes that would work. See my update.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I think this is better that property injection.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik: I added a third option.

Comment: so this is not a specific feature of the container, but you made multiple settings classes using generic, so it's a way around the problem, right?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik: This solution is indeed not container specific, but I wouldn't go as far as saying that this is a good general solution. As always: it depends.